# TI connect gives error "the name for this variable is not valid" on file transfer

Tags: basic

I've written some code for my TI-84+ calculator using an online tool called cemetech, but I receive the above error when trying to transfer the code to my calculator via USB and the TI-Connect software.

I've done some research and apparently this problem can arise when there's a problem with the code, but I don't know enough about TI Basic to know if I've done something wrong or not.  This is what I'm trying to transfer:

```
Prompt x
Prompt y
Prompt w
(x-y)/w->z
Disp z
If z=0.00:then:a=.5000
If z=0.01:then:a=.5040
...(and so on until z=0.49)
Disp a
```

I wasn't able to find any articles related to TI Basic here, so I'm not sure if I'm in the right place or not, but any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equals sign (=) tests equality, which you probably don't want. You want the assignment operator, (→). Also, I don't see any `End` statements. `If:Then:` requires `End`. For your code, you don't need the `Then`, your code should be something like

```
Prompt x
Prompt y
Prompt w
(x-y)/w→z
Disp z
If z=0.00:.5000→a
If z=0.01:.5040→a
...(and so on until z=0.49)
Disp a
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense, and I like it, but I'm still running in to the same issue.  I also changed it to a format I know should work:

`If z=0.00
 .5000->a`

This ran in to the same error, and I know that there's no problem with that code on my calculator.  I'm convinced that the problem is with the tool.  Do you know of any tools that would allow me to edit TI-Basic on the computer?  This program would require a lot of data entry, and would take longer than is feasible to complete on the calculator.

Comment: Thank you for your edits to my code.  At least I know how to write the program now.  I always get the "=" and "->" operator confused.  Not sure what's wrong with the transfer.

Comment: As for a computer tool, you can find a couple [here](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/sk:computer-setup) (I won't be more specific, since I don't want this to be an opinion piece).

Comment: As for `If z=0.00 .5000→a`, this wouldn't work as you are not separating the two statements; there is and `If z=0.00` statement, and an `.5000→a` statement. There must be either a new line or a colon between them.

Comment: As for efficiency and code size, you can replace 0.00 with 0, .5 for .5000, .504 for .5040, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Butting in for a moment:

If you are trying to store data into a variable using TI Connect, then:

Use the list of tools on the left hand side and go to:

Char > Keypad > (first option should be an arrow like you'd get with STO> button)

this should allow you to store your data into your variable of choice.

If you weren't looking for this information, my apologies for butting in =)